# Chat box on Meta is laggy

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The "X people chatting" box to the right hand site on Meta.SO is very laggy: It tends to be massively out of date, and thus gives misleading information about the people present and the last post in each chat room.

It's not really a big deal, but it's notably out of sync all the time.

Can it be brought up to speed a bit?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed a while ago; it shouldn't be out of sync more than two or three minutes now.

Comment: Yeah, I can't remember having seen that problem since.

Comment: We seem to have the issue back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253185/252153

Answer (score 5):

It *looks* like the initial loaded contents are cached for a long time; that panel also updates itself every minute. For example, currently I see "7 secs ago - Benjol" (which is quite out of date - Benjol spoke [just over 20 minutes ago](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/449350#449350)), but (waiting...) I now see "20 mins ago - Dan Grossman" ([which is correct](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/449351#449351)).

I'll investigate why this is cached so aggressively.