# "last post" time on chat not showing correct

Tags: bug, status-completed

Me again.

The "last active" (or last post/message) time on the sidebar chat boxes are all showing 23:51/23:52 on Jan 4th and there's been a lot of action in at least some of those rooms since then. Seen on SF, Meta.SO, SU and Gam1ng. (1 for those that may be blocked due to workplace filtering).

Windows 7 32-bit, IE 8, 12:47 GMT. 
[image]

Comment: Additional information on what the problem is can be found in [my comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75561/cached-chat-error-data-breaks-the-chat-ads/75589#comment-183480).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was fixed earlier today (before you posted, honest!). I'm just waiting on the next build.

Comment: @Mark Gravell: heh, thanks. Not that it muatter much but how often are builds pushed? I'm guessing the "revision: 2011.1.20.3" in bottom right corner is 3rd build today?

Comment: @tombull89 - it isn't fixed