# Incorrect "last post" time for chat room

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface

The last time I posted in the Posse Comitatus chat room was 20 days ago, yet the http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ page claims I posted there 3 hours ago:

---

[image]

---

- I am not sure if this shows up for everyone.
- It might have something to do with the room being frozen and
  unfrozen.
- [It might have something to do with this earlier bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75648/200500)

Comment: Yes, Adam Lear just unfroze the room a few hours ago. This looks similar to the reopen bug, where it shows a question being active by the last editor just because it got reopened... You were the last person to post anything there.

Comment: I'll let a developer make the official call, but I am close to positive that it was due to the room being frozen. These don't often 'thaw' and decay in a granular way, so it's not surprising that this simply wasn't noticed.