# The chat box is lagging behind

Tags: bug, chat, caching, sidebar

The chat box in the sidebar is constantly lagging behind. Right now on math.SE it's showing this:
[image]

But in reality, four math.SE rooms have been active since then, and there has been ample time for the box to update (1h-2h). But it hasn't. Is this by design (very aggressively cached)? Or is this a bug?

Note: I'm aware of these two earlier bug reports: [(1)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74790/chat-box-on-meta-is-laggy), [(2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75648/last-post-time-on-chat-not-showing-correct?lq=1), but they are supposed to have been fixed in 2011.

Comment: It's cached for several hours, always been like that, so feature request not a bug. :/

Comment: If you look at the bug reports I linked, a dev explicitly said ["it shouldn't be out of sync more than two or three minutes now"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92899/262767), so this is actually probably a regression, or something that was later changed to deal with increasing traffic.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Tim Chrome 41.0.2272.118 on Windows 8.1, if that changes anything (I don't see how the browser could change something like that, though. A quick test shows the same bug on Firefox and IE).

Comment: I wondered if it was a browser caching differently.

Comment: @Tim It's not the browser that's caching anything in this situation (well, maybe the pictures? That's completely beside the point). It's the SE server that's caching information about recently active chat rooms instead of having to update the info every time someone loads a page.

Comment: Well, lots of things change in four years, probably some change in chat code overwrote that fix back to the initial state. Like I said, I don't remember ever seeing this box up to date, so I always assumed that's how it should be.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Just to note, 4 years is a awful lot of time. Thing's might have changed. Also, I've seen this issue's even worse on betas. They sometimes don't sync for 4 hours!